# Postgres dynamic filter conditions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to dynamically filter through data based on condition, which is stored in specific column. This condition can change for every row.
For example I have a table *my_table* with couple of columns, one of them is called *foo*, where there are couple of filter conditions such as ***AND bar > 1*** or in the next row ***AND bar > 2*** or in the next row ***AND bar = 33***.
I have a query which looks like:

```
SELECT something from somewhere 
LEFT JOIN otherthing on some_condition
WHERE first_condition AND second_condition AND 
here_i_want_dynamically_load_condition_from_my_table.foo
```

What is the correct way to do it? I have read some articles about dynamic queries, but I am not able to find a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible in pure SQL: at query time, the planner has to know your exact logic. Now, you can hide it away in a function (in pseudo-sql):

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_I_filter_or_not(some_id) RETURNS boolean AS '
    BEGIN
        value = select some_value from table where id = some_id
        condition_type = SELECT ... --Query a condition type for this row
        condition_value = SELECT ... --Query a condition value for this row
        if condition_type = 'equals' and condition_value = value 
           return true
        if condition_type = 'greater_than' and condition_value < value 
           return true
        if condition_type = 'lower_than' and condition_value > value 
           return true
        return false;
    END;
'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And query it like this:

```
SELECT something 
FROM somewhere 
LEFT JOIN otherthing on some_condition
WHERE first_condition 
  AND second_condition
  AND do_I_filter_or_not(somewhere.id)
```

Now the performance will be bad: you have to invoke that function potentially on every row in the query; triggering lots of subqueries.

---

Thinking about it, if you just want <, >, =, and you have a table (filter_criteria) describing for each id what the criteria is you can do it:

```
CREATE TABLE filter_criteria AS(
  some_id integer,
  equals_threshold integer,
  greater_than_threshold integer,
  lower_than_threshold integer
  -- plus a check that two thresholds must be null, and one not null
)

INSERT INTO filter_criteria (1, null, 5, null); -- for > 5
```

And query like this:

```
SELECT something 
FROM somewhere 
LEFT JOIN otherthing on some_condition
LEFT JOIN filter_criteria USING (some_id)
WHERE first_condition 
  AND second_condition
  AND COALESCE(bar = equals_threshold, true)
  AND COALESCE(bar > greater_than_threshold, true)
  AND COALESCE(bar < lower_than_threshold, true)
```

The `COALESCE`s are here to default to not filtering (`AND true`) if the threshold is missing (bar = equals_threshold will yield null instead of a boolean).

The planner has to know your exact logic at query time: now you're just doing 3 passes of filtering, with a =, <, > check each time. That'd still be more performant than idea #1 with all the subquerying.